# Column is of type timestamp without time zone but expression is of type character varying : Nifi

Tags: csv, timestamp, apache-nifi, timescaledb

I am trying to insert CSV records to Postgres database using nifi.

Sample csv file :

```
timenow,location
'2019-10-21 15:13:11','colombo'
```

When nifi scenario runs, it gives following error

> Error column 'timenow' is of type timestamp without time zone but expression is of type character varying

If I use normal `insert into conditions (timenow,location) values ('2019-10-21 15:13:11','colombo');`

No errors values inserted to table. Do I have to change nifi configurations to add this to table?

I have changed Nifi CSVReader -> Timestamp format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`

EDIT: After first comment
Nifi generated query is : `INSERT INTO public.conditions (timenow, location) VALUES ('2019-10-21 15:13:11','colombo')`

I have used this with timescaledb terminal and it inserted the record.

Comment: Can you see the SQL Nifi is executing against your database? Because if you take that CSV file and try to COPY it into TImescaleDB it is ok.

Comment: @BlagojAtanasovski `INSERT INTO public.conditions (timenow, location) VALUES ('2019-10-21 15:13:11','colombo')`, if I run this on my timescale terminal, it inserts a record.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was a simple fix in nifi side.

In **DBCPConnectionPool** -> Database URL -> `jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/databaseName?stringtype=unspecified`

Answer was given by  ajaytigga0210 on [Facing issues with Date and Timestamp Columns](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Facing-issues-with-Date-and-Timestamp-Columns/td-p/194902)