# How to connect to a remote postgresql using apache nifi

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, apache-nifi

I am trying to run `apache-nifi` one server and postgresql in a remote server.

When I try to insert records to remote database, I get following error.

> java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class
>   'org.postgresql.Driver' for connect URL
>   'jdbc:postgresql//123.456.789.12:5432/test?stringtype=unspecified'

Here I use `stringtype=unspecified` as it was the solution for :
 [Column is of type timestamp without time zone but expression is of type character varying : Nifi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58485589/column-is-of-type-timestamp-without-time-zone-but-expression-is-of-type-characte)

In my **PutDatabaseRecord** processor.

**Database Connection URL** : `jdbc:postgresql//123.456.789.12:5432/test?stringtype=unspecified`

**Database Driver Class Name** : `org.postgresql.Driver`

**Database Driver Location(s)** : `/opt/postgresql-42.2.8.jre6.jar`

jar file is placed on both servers at same location. What am I missing? should nifi and database run in a same server?

Edit : `nifi-log`

> 2019-10-29 07:35:23,062 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-8]
>   o.a.n.p.standard.PutDatabaseRecord
>   PutDatabaseRecord[id=f1fcb902-a1a2-364e-8223-971e4d0dfa46] Failed to
>   process session due to
>   org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException:
>   java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class
>   'org.postgresql.Driver' for connect URL
>   'jdbc:postgresql//123.456.789.12:5432/test?stringtype=unspecified':
>   org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException:
>   java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class
>   'org.postgresql.Driver' for connect URL
>   'jdbc:postgresql//123.456.789.12:5432/test?stringtype=unspecified'
>   org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException:
>   java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class
>   'org.postgresql.Driver' for connect URL
>   'jdbc:postgresql//123.456.789.12:5432/test?stringtype=unspecified'

Comment: show full stacktrace from the nifi log file. there should be details of this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add `:` in your database connection URL and check

`jdbc:postgresql://123.456.789.12:5432/test?stringtype=unspecified`